cupy.transpose() not working the same as numpy.transpose()
I am trying to get the indicies when finding the non-zero values of an array using cupy. I first used Numpy as so np.transpose(np.nonzero(a)) which works just fine, but when changing it to cupy cp.transpose(cp.nonzero(a)) it fails and I get this error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'transpose'.
I've read the doocumentation and there doesn't seem to be any difference between the two so I don't know what could be wrong.
Thank you for teh help.
I've tried seeing if it was the cp.nonzero(a) function that was making a difference but the output seems to be exactly the same so I am a bit lost in what else to try.

I have found a solution but I don't know if it is the most efficient way:
cp.transpose(cp.asarray(cp.nonzero(a)))

Another approach to achieve the same result is to use cp.where() instead of cp.nonzero(). So cp.where() offers more flexibility as it allows you to specify conditions other than non-zero values if needed. See the sample code I dropped here at code dump.

np.nonzero returns a tuple of arrays.  np.transpose, if given a tuple or list, first turns it into an array. and then applies its transpose method.  This is true for many numpy functions that have a method of the same name.

Check the source code of cp.transpose (link in docs).  All it does return a.transpose(axes).  A tuple does not have a transpose method!

Look at the code. np.where with only one argument calls nonzero.  numpy wants us to use nonzero in this case.  In any case using cp.where doesn't solve the tuple issue.

np.argwhere just does np.transpose(np.nonzero(a)). cp.argwhere calls np.argwhere.  Eitherway thiis transpose turns a n-tuple into an n-column array, where n is the number of dimensions of a.  The nonzero tuple can be used directly for indexing.  The transpose is better for a slower iterative indexing.
